# Sub select in linq to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
select new EmployeeModel
{
 Title = (emp.DEPT == null ? tmsg.Label : db.DEPARTMENT.Where(o => o.Id == emp.DEPT).FirstOrDefault().DEPARTMENT_TRAD.Where(o => o.Language == locale).FirstOrDefault().Label) + " " + DbFunctions.AddMinutes(emp.Date, adjustedoffsetInMins),
}
from DEPARTMENT
where EMPId= 10;
```

I want to convert the sub select in the Title select to a simple sql request.
Any idea of how to do that please?

Comment: It may not required to use sub query, so it would better to share table with few data to get better answers.